# label widget not updating with 'after' method in Tkinter for-loop

Tags: time, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to update the text of and display a label inside of a for-loop in tkinter.  This should happen after a second, according to the .after method.

```
def rightString(self, gro, string):
    for z in string:
        self.message2.configure(text="Good job, %s is a member of %s!" % (z, gro.getName()))

        root.after(1000)
        self.message2.grid()
        print(z, " should be displayed!")
```

I hope this is enough info; I feel like there is something very basic I'm missing.  The print function calls and displays each of the members of 'string' in IDLE.  I don't understand why self.message2 does not display.  It displays in other parts of the script which do not include 'after' methods.

I will post more of the code if it is necessary.

Thanks.

Comment: `self.message2.configure()` is enough - you don't have to call `self.message2.grid()` again.

Comment: @A.Rodas  I don't think that affects the outcome.  I just tried it without calling grid again, didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the text of the label each second, then you have to schedule the function again with `after`:

```
def rightString(self, gro, string):
    if string:
        z = string[0]
        self.message2.configure(text="Good job, %s is a member of %s!" % (z, gro.getName()))
        root.after(1000, lambda: self.rightString(gro, string[1:])
        print(z, " should be displayed!")
```

As I've said in my comment, calling `grid()` each time you change the text is not necessary.

---

*Edit:* To execute a different function when the processing of all strings has finished, you can add a call to it in an `else` block:

```
def rightString(self, gro, string):
    if string:
        # ...
    else:
        doSomethingElse()
```

Comment: I am using this method as part of a class, and I have several commands following the method call.  For some reason this method gets called once, string[0] is displayed, and then it jumps right into the following commands in the class.  It continues through the 'string' list only afterwards.  Do you know how I can modify this so that it won't continue past def rightString until it is commpleted?  Thanks.

Comment: @DavidJ. I have added a possible solution to that to my answer.

Comment: You use the word "recursively" but this isn't really recursion (which to some has a negative connotation). The function doesn't call itself, the function simply puts itself on a queue, to be called later by the event loop.

Comment: @BryanOakley True, strictly speaking this is not recursion - what I don't understand is why it can have a negative connotation to someone.

Comment: @A.Rodas: recursion is misunderstood by many*, and those of us who've been around the block a few times know that it's dangerous in the wrong hands. (* I used to not think that was true, but I swear, 75% of the people my team interviews cannot write the simplest of recursive procedures).

Comment: @BryanOakley I see your point. I also think recursion algorithms are sometimes more difficult to understand than the iterative versions, but the experience from your interviews (75%!) is certainly surprising.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't display because you are preventing the event loop from processing events, specifically the event that causes it to redraw the window on the screen. You need to restructure your code to avoid calling `after` with just a single argument.